# multiple handcrafted labels for figure

Tags: floats, cross-referencing, captions, back-referencing

The following MWE shows my attempt to create a list of references in a document, with links from text to reference and back. It works well in text, but badly in figures when I try make the reference link follow the caption.

Hyperlinks work correctly but their text representations are wrong.

This may be an xy-problem (http://mywiki.wooledge.org/XyProblem). If there's a better solution than my attempted hack, feel free...

I've played with subcaptions as suggested at 
[How to put two labels for one figure](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/219168/how-to-put-two-labels-for-one-figure) with no success.

[image]

[image]

[image]

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{answers}
\usepackage{environ}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{xifthen}
%\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\newcommand{\referencesFilename}{references}
\newcounter{csmrefcounter}
\newcounter{gotoref}

\NewEnviron{csmr}[1][]{%
\refstepcounter{csmrefcounter}
\stepcounter{gotoref}
\ifthenelse{\isempty{#1}}
    {[R\ref{RR\arabic{gotoref}}]% not inside figure
     \label{R\arabic{csmrefcounter}}
    }
    {\caption{#1 [R\ref{RR\arabic{gotoref}}]}% inside figure
    \label{R\arabic{csmrefcounter}}
    }%
\Writetofile{\referencesFilename}{\protect\item[R\ref{R\arabic{csmrefcounter}}]}
\Writetofile{\referencesFilename}{\protect\refstepcounter{gotoref}}
\Writetofile{\referencesFilename}{\protect\label{RR\arabic{gotoref}}}
\Writetofile{\referencesFilename}{\BODY }
}

\newcommand{\getreferences}{%
\newpage
\chapter{References} 
\setcounter{gotoref}{0}
\begin{itemize}
\input{\referencesFilename}
\end{itemize}
}

\begin{document}

\Opensolutionfile{\referencesFilename}

\chapter{Fermi Problems}

\begin{quotation}
Every day the National Security Agency intercepts and
stores \emph{1.7 billion} international e-mails, phone calls, texts and
other communications.%
\begin{csmr}
ACLU National Newsletter, Summer 2012. Testing behavior if this is a
very long reference, perhaps spanning multiple lines. 
\end{csmr}
\end{quotation}

Here's a second reference
\begin{csmr}
Second text reference.
\end{csmr}
inline in the text.

Now test the referencing mechanism for figures.

\begin{figure}
\centering
FIGURE 1 - without a reference
\caption{caption for Figure 1}
\label{fig:1}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}
\centering
FIGURE 2 - with a reference
\begin{csmr}[caption for Figure 2 - correct reference label here:]
Reference for Figure 2. The link goes to the right place, but displays
incorrectly, showing the figure number rather than the reference number.
\end{csmr}
\label{fig:2}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}
\centering
FIGURE 3 - without a reference
\caption{caption for Figure 3}
\label{fig:3}
\end{figure}

Try to refer to the figure labels: first one is
\ref{fig:1}, second is \ref{fig:2}, third is 
\ref{fig:3}. Note that the link to Figure 2 displays the (wrong!)
reference number rather than the figure number, but goes the the right
place. 

\Closesolutionfile{\referencesFilename}

\getreferences 

\end{document}
```

Comment: Why don't you use LaTeX's built-in cross-reference and footnote systems and a bibliographic package like biblatex?

Comment: @AndrewCashner I have about 200-300 references with varying formats, often free text. To maintain my document I have to keep the reference text where the reference is in the document rather than in another file. "Footnotes" might work if there were a robust backreferencing mechanism (that worked for figures and tables too). I'm more than willing to be educated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd hoped a local wizard would provide an answer quickly. Since no one did, I worked it out for myself in time, with help from
[Understanding how references and labels work](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/111280/understanding-how-references-and-labels-work) and
[How to use \ref to print the value of a counter the way it was originally produced?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/257757/how-to-use-ref-to-print-the-value-of-a-counter-the-way-it-was-originally-produc), particularly this comment from @ChristianHupfer :

> You must use the label for the linenumber, say \label{f1} in the first
>   column always, since ***\label does always look after the last counter
>   being increased with \refstepcounter***. If you use \label in the
>   \footnotemark column, it will use the wrong counter then! –  Christian
>   Hupfer yesterday

I rearranged the counter increments and the labels accordingly. Here's the revised environment definition:

```
\NewEnviron{csmr}[1][]{%
\stepcounter{gotoref}
\ifthenelse{\isempty{#1}}
    {[R\ref{RR\arabic{gotoref}}]% not inside figure
     \refstepcounter{csmrefcounter}
     \label{R\arabic{csmrefcounter}}
    }
    {% inside figure - the caption passed as the argument has the
     % label, e.g. #1 might expand to
     % The first figure\label{fig:numberone}
     \caption{#1 [R\ref{RR\arabic{gotoref}}]}
     \refstepcounter{csmrefcounter}
     \label{R\arabic{csmrefcounter}}
    }%
\Writetofile{\referencesFilename}{\protect\item[R\ref{R\arabic{csmrefcounter}}]}
\Writetofile{\referencesFilename}{\protect\refstepcounter{gotoref}}
\Writetofile{\referencesFilename}{\protect\label{RR\arabic{gotoref}}}
\Writetofile{\referencesFilename}{\BODY }
}
```