# How to use \ref to print the value of a counter the way it was originally produced?

Tags: cross-referencing, counters

I want to number the lines in a table with roman numerals, and then when I cross-reference them have the reference printed in the same way.

For example,

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\newcounter{foo}
\newcommand{\rfoo}{\refstepcounter{foo}(\roman{foo})}

\begin{tabular}{r|l}

\hline

\rfoo\label{f1} & First line \\ \hline

\rfoo\label{f2} & Second line \\ \hline

\hline
\end{tabular}

\

The first line is \ref{f1}.  The second line is \ref{f2}.

\end{document}
```

gives

[image]

But what I want is:

[image]

Comment: See my possible answer. I will update with an automatic row numbering code later on

Comment: Small tip: `\newcounter` should be done before `\begin{document}`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Each counter has a fellow macro called `\the...`, say counter `foo` will have `\thefoo`. This `\the...` macro does by default the output of the counter value with arabic numbers.

`\thefoo` is used also for the label as it is written to the `.aux` file. If format `(i)`, is requested, this has to be written into the `.aux` file and it's to be used in `\thefoo`.

So

```
\renewcommand{\thefoo}{(\roman{foo})}
```

is the name of the game ;-)

```
\documentclass{article}



\newcounter{foo}
\renewcommand{\thefoo}{(\roman{foo})}
\newcommand{\rfoo}{\refstepcounter{foo}\thefoo}

\begin{document} 
\begin{tabular}{r|l}

\hline

\rfoo\label{f1} & First line \\ \hline

\rfoo\label{f2} & Second line \\ \hline

\hline
\end{tabular}



The first line is \ref{f1}.  The second line is \ref{f2}.

\end{document}
```

[image]

**Here the automatic row numbering version**

```
\documentclass{article}


\usepackage{array}

\newcounter{foo}
\renewcommand{\thefoo}{(\roman{foo})}

% Define
\newcolumntype{R}{>{\refstepcounter{foo}\thefoo\arraybackslash}r}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{R|l}

\hline

\label{f1} & First line \\ \hline

\label{f2} & Second line \\ \hline

 & ... line \\ \hline

\label{f4}  & ... line \\ \hline


\hline
\end{tabular}

\

The first line is \ref{f1}.  The second line is \ref{f2}.

And in line \ref{f4} you can see that

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: No comments please on the design of the table ;-)

Comment: Thanks Christian!  But how do I get \ref{f1} to print the relevant value of the new counter "foo" that I've introduced.  I've used a second new counter that's interfering.

Comment: @DeliaRuby: What do you mean by `relevant` value of `foo`? The real arabic number?

Comment: Sorry I wasn't clear.  This is related to the "more than one footnote in a table" question that I asked yesterday.   Someone gave me a great way to get \footnotemark and \footnotetext to work right when I wanted more than one footnote in a table.  It involved introducing another new counter.  So now, when I want to use "\ref{f1}" to get "(i)" it doesn't use the format used in "thefoo", but rather that for the other counter ("dummycounter").  Should I put up the mwe?

Comment: @DeliaRuby: I was the `someone` :-P And you accepted and (unaccepted :-() my answer. Wait, I will look about it ...

Comment: @DeliaRuby: I don't get what you want to achieve now. The dummycounter in that answer isn't really shown at all, so there is no need to output it

Comment: Oh, so you were! :)  This is all in the same table. The problem is that when I try to reference the line number (i) using \ref{f1}, what I get is "3", where that was the number of times that "dummycounter" had been incremented.

Comment: @DeliaRuby: Ah, now I get you ;-) You **must** use the label for the linenumber, say `\label{f1}` in the first column always, since `\label` does always look after the last counter being increased with `\refstepcounter`. If you use `\label` in the `\footnotemark` column, it will use the wrong counter then!

Answer (score 2):

`\label` write `\theX` of the last counter `X`, so update this accordingly:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcounter{foo}
\renewcommand{\thefoo}{(\roman{foo})}
\newcommand{\rfoo}{\refstepcounter{foo}\thefoo}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{r|l}
  \hline
  \rfoo\label{f1} & First line \\
  \rfoo\label{f2} & Second line \\
  \hline
\end{tabular}

The first line is~\ref{f1}. The second line is~\ref{f2}.

\end{document}
```

As reference, see [Understanding how references and labels work](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/111280/5764).