# Cross reference custom ID

Tags: cross-referencing

I have a table of requirements that have an ID associated with each one, I'm doing this via:

```
\stepcounter{functionalrequirements}FR\arabic{functionalrequirements}
```

I'm wondering if there is a way to do for example something like:

```
\stepcounter{functionalrequirements}FR\arabic{functionalrequirements}\label{requirement-user-interface}
```

and then reference like:

```
As seen in requirement \ref{requirement-user-interface}
```

Comment: Just use `\refstepcounter` instead of `\stepcounter`

Comment: You probably want `\ref{..}` to return `FR<num>`, correct? Or should it just return `<num>`?

Comment: Related question and answer (perhaps more complex than what you need): http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/255938/multiple-handcrafted-labels-for-figure

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps the following template might suit your needs:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\newcounter{functionalrequirement}
\renewcommand{\thefunctionalrequirement}{FR\arabic{functionalrequirement}}
\newcommand{\newFR}{%
  \refstepcounter{functionalrequirement}%
  \thefunctionalrequirement}

\usepackage{lipsum}% Just for this example
\usepackage{booktabs}
\begin{document}

\lipsum[1]

See, for example,~\ref{fr:first} and~\ref{fr:second} below:
\begin{center}
  \begin{tabular}{ll}
    \toprule
    Reference & Description \\
    \midrule
    \newFR\label{fr:first}  & First \\
    \newFR\label{fr:second} & Second \\
    \bottomrule
  \end{tabular}
\end{center}

\lipsum[2]

\end{document}
```

Principally you want to use `\refstepcounter{<cntr>}` to increment the counter. This internally does a `\stepcounter{<cntr>}`, but also updates LaTeX's referencing mechanism by `\the<cntr>`. You'll note that I've updated `\the<cntr>` above to prepend it with `FR`. You can remove this if you only want the reference to be the number.